# if request is not post then to redirect to another route

Tags: laravel

```
 $checkMethod = $request->method();
        if (!$checkMethod) {
            return redirect('todo_show');
        } else {
            echo "yes";
        }
```

if request is not post then how can i redirect to another route. This error occured "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST".

Comment: Post your route code

Answer (score 1):

Change your route `Route::post...` to `Route::any...` or `Route::match(['GET', 'POST')]…`
And as per [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-the-request-method) you can check this request method on your controller  :

```
$method = $request->method();
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    return redirect('todo_show');
} else {
    echo "yes";
}
```

Comment: code for to return to another html page or view

Comment: `return view('view_page');`

Comment: $checkMethod = $request->method();
        if ($checkMethod != 'POST') {
            return view('todo_show');
        } else {
            echo "yes";
        }